# Magento pagination for custom collection

Tags: php, mysql, collections, pagination, magento-1.9

I have created a module in which i am using pagination.I have 901 products which satisfy my filtered collection but i want to get only 360 products. see below code for more understanding..

```
class Test_Module_Block_Listmore extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List 
{ 
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

    }   

    public function _getProductCollection()
    {

        $time =  time();
        $lastTime = $time - 7776000; // 90*60*24*60
        $from = date('Y-m-d', $lastTime);
        $to = date('Y-m-d', $time);
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $attribute_code = "country_code"; 
        $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("catalog_product", $attribute_code); 
        $options = $attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false); 
            foreach($options as $option)
            { 
                $value=$option["value"]; 
                $label=$option["label"]; 
                if($label=='SG')
                {
                    $sg=$option["value"];
                }
                if($label=='MY')
                {
                    $my=$option["value"];
                }
            }

            $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                            ->setStoreId($storeId)
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'country_code',array('in'=> array($sg,$my)))))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('publication_date', array('lteq' => date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") ))
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('gr_date', array('lteq' => date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") ))     
                            ->addAttributeToSort('publication_date', 'DESC');

            $categoryWise = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
            if($categoryWise){

                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryWise);
                if($_category->getChildren()){

                   $products->getSelect()
                        ->join(array('category'=>"catalog_category_product"),"e.entity_id=category.product_id") 
                        ->where("category.category_id = '".$_category->getId()."' or category.category_id in (".$_category->getChildren().")");
                }else{

                    $products->getSelect()
                        ->join(array('category'=>"catalog_category_product"),"e.entity_id=category.product_id") 
                        ->where("category.category_id = '".$_category->getId()."'");
                }

                 $products->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');

            }


        $products->setPageSize(360);

        $this->_productCollection = $products;

        return $this->_productCollection;               
    }
    }
```

but when i go to front end it show me pagination according to 901 products. when I echo $this->_productCollection->getSize() it shows me 901 records but when I use $this->_productCollection->count() it shows me 360 records. how can I get pagination for only 360 records for my custom filtered collection.

Answer (score 0):

with method

```
setPageSize()
```

you are setting the amount of collection items per one page of pagination

if you want to limit your collection to 360 items:

```
$products->getSelect()->limit(360);

$this->_productCollection = $products;

return $this->_productCollection;
```

> And make sure to load the collection to get appropriate values.
>   (method count() will do)